I have a problem when using gdal's vsimem feature
Code like this：
calculate_boundary_weights(polys_in_area, scale=config.boundary_scale).to_file("/vsimem/weights.vrt")
gdal.Rasterize(mem_ds, "/vsimem/weights.vrt", bands=[n_bands+2], burnValues=[1], allTouched=True)

Here is the problem：
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/songzirui/桌面/planetunet-nonorm/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    preprocessing.preprocess_all(config)
  File "/home/songzirui/桌面/planetunet-nonorm/preprocessing.py", line 233, in preprocess_all
    gdal.Rasterize(mem_ds, "/vsimem/weights.vrt", bands=[n_bands+2], burnValues=[1], allTouched=True)
  File "/home/songzirui/anaconda3/envs/tfgdal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 1526, in Rasterize
    srcDS = OpenEx(srcDS, gdalconst.OF_VECTOR)
  File "/home/songzirui/anaconda3/envs/tfgdal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 4720, in OpenEx
    return _gdal.OpenEx(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: No such file or directory

I can't figure out the exact usage of gdal's vsimem, but I can print the content of "calculate_boundary_weights(polys_in_area, scale=config.boundary_scale)", I wonder why I can't write the content in /vsimem/weights.

It looks like .to_file("/vsimem/weights.vrt") isn't throwing an error. Have you checked if the file /vsimem/weights.vrt is actually created? You should also check to ensure the user running the process has the permissions needed to read and write in the /vsimem directory. Perhaps try a local directory first.

Everyone has permission to write in /vsimem/. However I am not sure if calculate_boundary_weights can use GDAL's VFS. What is this, where does it come from? GDAL has an API that can list the files in /vsimem/, check if the file is created.

Thank you！But i dont konw how to list  files in /vsimem/. i can't find it in gdal's documents
